# Dependent objects - dependency injection using unity C#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

We have a Console App which refers to third party custom dlls. To create an object of 3rd party dlls, we have used Unity Dependency Injection using Unity.config

Now,the 3rd party classes are dependent.

```
class A : IA
{ 
}

class B : IB
{
    B(IA obja) {}
}
```

Using Unity dependency for the above scenario, how do we resolve the dependency ??

Comment: You register your types for `IA` and `IB` with Unity.

Answer (score 0):

> Using Unity dependency for the above scenario, how do we resolve the dependency?

Only thing you should do is properly setup `unity` with all required dependencies. During the resolution `unity` will handle dependencies for you and inject setup implementation...

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Foo();
}

public interface IBar
{
    void Bar();
}


public class Foo : IFoo
{
    string IFoo.Foo()
    {
        return "Foo";
    }
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    private readonly IFoo _foo;

    public Bar(IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    void IBar.Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Bar {_foo.Foo()}");
    }
}
```

Imagine this situation `Bar` is dependand on `IFoo`. By registering both `IBar` and `IFoo` you will provide enough information to unity to be able to resolve dependencies for you...

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>();
container.RegisterType<IBar, Bar>();

var bar = container.Resolve<IBar>(); // Foo will be automatically injected
bar.Bar();
// Bar Foo
```